# vb.net list confusion

Tags: vb.net, list

I am looping through a list for a spellchecker in vb.net (using vs 2010).  I want to go through a wrongly spelled word list. Each time the code picks the index that's one higher than the index of the last checked word.

In my version of notquiteVB/Pythonese I think it would translate something like:

```
(start loop)
dim i as Integer = 0  
dim word as String
word = words_to_check_at_spellcheck.Item(0 + i)
i = i+1
(end loop)
```

But this doesn't work at all...when it gets to the last item in the list and reaches 'word = ' it throws the error of 'out of range -- must be less than the size of the collection'.

How do you get the last item in a list? Maybe lists aren't what VB uses for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're collection of misspelled words is named **mispelled**:

```
For Each word As String In mispelled
    'Do something
Next
```

Comment: As an explanation. VB.net is able to take collections of items such as lists and arrays and do a split on them using this technique. If you didn't pick up on it, you are starting with the first item in "mispelled" and then doing whatever is inside the loop. You do that for each item. You don't have to worry about collection size this way so you wont get any out of range errors.

Comment: Thanks to both for the answer.